# forで回して作成した複数のヒストグラムにサブタイトルを追加したい

Tags: r

下記のスクリプトだと、サブタイトルに `subtitle_file[i, 2]` のすべてが結合された状態で追加されてしまいます。私は、ヒストグラムが作成されるたびに、 `subtitle_file[i, 2]` の1つが順番に追加されるスクリプトを作成したいです。

ヒストグラム作成に使用するファイル数とID_Name.txtの行数は一致しています。

```
# サブタイトルを格納するための変数を初期化
subtitle <- ""

# サブタイトルを格納するCSVファイルを読み込み、1行ずつ処理する
subtitle_file <- read.csv("ID_Name.txt", header = FALSE)
for (i in 1:nrow(subtitle_file)) {
  # サブタイトルを変数に格納する
  subtitle <- paste(subtitle, subtitle_file[i, 2], sep = " ")
}

path <- './path/'
files <- list.files(path)
n <- length(files)

for (i in 1:n){
  file <- paste('./path/', files[i], sep = "")
  print(file)
  
  data <-read.csv(file)
  f_out <- paste('./path/', files[i], '.png', sep = "")
  print(f_out)
  png(f_out)  # 描画デバイスを開く
  hist(data[,2],main = "",xlab = "あああ",ylab = "いいい",sub = subtitle)
  dev.off()         # 描画デバイスを閉じる
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ベクタにすればよいでしょう。

```r
df <- read.csv("ID_Name.txt", header = FALSE)
subtitle <- df[,2]
          :

for (i in 1:n){
          :

  hist(data[,2],main = "",xlab = "あああ",ylab = "いいい",sub = subtitle[i])
          :

}
```